# Is it possible to disable commitEditingStyle programmatically?

Tags: swift, action, tableview, edit

In my tableview, I only want certain cells to be able to drag to the left for some options based on a condition. The other cells should behave as if `commitEditingStyle` is disabled. Is this possible?

With the code below, I can add the actions when the conditions are met but the other cells still get the default "delete" action. How do I get rid of that delete action?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let object = items[indexPath.row]
    if object.name == "name" {

        // someAction
        var addAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "+") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        }
        return [addAction]
    }
    return nil
}
```

With the code below I managed to enable and disable the actions. But only with the `Delete` button.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    let object = items[indexPath.row]
    if object.name == "joyce" {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want a way to determine editable state based on your data model. For example:

```
class Message
{
    var subject : String
    var title : String
    var isEditable : Bool

    init(subject: String, title: String)
    {
        self.subject = subject
        self.title = title
        self.isEditable = true
    }
}
```

With this, you can easily handle the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Your view controller should look something like this:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var tableView : UITableView!
    var messages : [Message]

    // MARK: - UITableView Delegate

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.messages.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        return message.isEditable
    }
}
```

In some more complex examples it may be a computed property but the overall concept is the same.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
  canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool`.

From Apple documentation:

> The method permits the data source to exclude individual
>   rows from being treated as editable. Editable rows display the
>   insertion or deletion control in their cells. If this method is not
>   implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable.

Comment: I forgot to add that i can manage to do exactly what i want, but only with getting the default delete action with the code `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        
        let object = items[indexPath.row]
        if object.name == "name" {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
        } else {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
        }
    }` Is it possible to use something similar to this?

Comment: If you disable editing for rows that do not match your condition, what's the difference between that and what you want?

Comment: sorry, i had the condition double. Got mixed up after trying to figure out for hours and mixing some things up :s, thanks anyway!